# How to create a clear button out out imageview?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, textview, imageview

So im currently doing a project that is due soon.

it consists of making a phone app with number buttons etc..

One of the questions that the teacher asked us is to add a Imageview and use it as a button to clear the TextView when there is 10 characters or over.

any help is appreciated, I'm still very new to Android coding so my knowledge is very bad haha

here is my Java code:

```
    Button no1,no2,no3,no4,no5,no6,no7,no8,no9,no0;
    TextView tv1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        no1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no1);
        no2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no2);
        no3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no3);
        no4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no4);
        no5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no5);
        no6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no6);
        no7=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no7);
        no8=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no8);
        no9=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no9);
        no0=(Button) findViewById(R.id.no0);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        no1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"1");
            }
        });
        no2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"2");
            }
        });
        no3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"3");
            }
        });
        no4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"4");
            }
        });
        no5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"5");
            }
        });
        no6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"6");
            }
        });
        no7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"7");
            }
        });
        no8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"8");
            }
        });
        no9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"9");
            }
        });
        no0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"0");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here Is my XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnclear"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/phone_on" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="404dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.994">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no8"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no9"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etoile"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Hashtag"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/etoile"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="*"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no0"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Hashtag"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etoile"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Hashtag"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="#"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/no0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And heres a Screenshot of my design:
[Design part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amXic.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you will need to make your ImageView clickable in the XML:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

You can then set the `OnClickListener` on the ImageView like you did for the rest of your Buttons.

Comment: ohhh, i already did that i think, i was confused about if we could actually use it as a button or not at first thanks for clarifying it for me !

Comment: so now that i put it as a clickable what can I do to make it clear the textview? but like only if there is 10 characters if there is less than 10 characters we cannot erase

Comment: If you get the text in your TextView, you can use the .length property and make a condition based on it. If it contains more then ten characters, just set the text with an empty string.

Comment: im very sorry i dont really understand how to use the .length since I'm very new . is it okay to ask if you could explain me how to use it in this situation? that would help me a lot, thanks

Comment: Using the methods getText().toString() on your TextView will return you a string, which you can use .length on as it is an array of characters. You can then make a condition with this number, like : if (tv1.getText().toString().length() > 10) { //Put the code to empty the TextView here }

Comment: ohh i see so the getText().toString() it put it inside the the onclicklistener i declare on the outside?

Comment: here is what i did till now : `btnclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv1.setText("");
            }
        }); `

Comment: This is a good start, you just need to make the condition for the 10 digits : btnclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
@Override             
public void onClick(View v) { 
    if (tv1.getText().toString().length() > 10) {             
        tv1.setText("");
     }             
  }         
});

Comment: wow! it is working i nearly arrived at the same thing but instead of writing the if inside I wrote it on the outside lol. but thank you so much, you're a lifesaver. been stuck on this for over two hours so I was thinking of giving up.

Comment: Beware if you put the `setOnClickListner` in the if, as if you click afterwards it will always clear the TextView. You should always try to put conditions in the `onClick` method.